# How to make a checkerboard matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I need to initialize a checkerboard matrix to merge two feature maps in my tensorflow graph, I was able to do it for a known shape using numpy beside TF like this

```
def checkerboard_concat(x1, x2):

    mask1 = np.ones((10,10,3))
    mask1[1::2,::2] = 0
    mask1[::2,1::2] = 0

    mask2 = np.zeros((10,10,3))
    mask2[1::2,::2] = 1
    mask2[::2,1::2] = 1

    return x1 * mask1 + x2 * mask2
```

But I was not able to do it with a dynamic shape, I used `tf.shape()` that returns an output of shape `(N,)` but I don't how to evaluate it dynamically.

Also, I tried using `tf.ones_like(x1)` but couldn't use subscripts to change it like a numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on modulo and XOR operations:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

def make_checkerboard(N):
    """
    Return a NxN checkerboard matrix M, i.e. with M(i,j) == True if (i+j) mod 2 == 1
    :param N:   Length of the checkerboard (can be dynamic)
    :return:    Boolean tensor of shape NxN
    """
    range_n = tf.range(N)
    odd_ind = tf.cast(tf.mod(range_n, 2), dtype=tf.bool)

    odd_rows = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(odd_ind , -1), [1, N])
    odd_cols = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(odd_ind ,  0), [N, 1])

    checker = tf.logical_xor(odd_rows, odd_cols)
    return checker

def checkerboard_concat(x1, x2, is_batch=True):

    dynamic_n = tf.shape(x1)[1 if is_batch else 0]
    mask2 = make_checkerboard(dynamic_n)
    mask2 = tf.expand_dims(mask2, -1)   # Expand masks to cover channels
    mask1 = tf.logical_not(mask2)

    return x1 * tf.cast(mask1, dtype=x1.dtype) + x2 * tf.cast(mask2, dtype=x2.dtype)


# Example:
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x1 = tf.ones((4,4,3), dtype=tf.int32)
x2 = tf.ones((4,4,3), dtype=tf.int32) * 2

x = checkerboard_concat(x1, x2, is_batch=False)
res = sess.run(x)
print(res[...,0])
# [[1 2 1 2]
#  [2 1 2 1]
#  [1 2 1 2]
#  [2 1 2 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, a note for others who would use this solution for a batch not a single example to use shape[1]

Comment: Yes, it requires some small changes to work with batches. I edited the code accordingly.